# ¿Cómo es la puntuación de citas de preguntas que tienen respuestas muy cercanas?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

Cuando se tiene un párrafo con preguntas autorrespondidas por el orador, ¿es correcto usar rayas para las respuestas del orador?

Por ejemplo:

> Mucha gente me pregunta: «¿Por qué no eres candidato?, —eso no es lo que yo elegí— ¿Pero por qué no te lanzas de alcalde si tienes tanta influencia?, —no importa la influencia, lo que importa es el deseo. Yo no quería eso—». Que yo quiero ser alcalde; uno no puede ser alcalde si no está dispuesto a renunciar a otras cosas, y yo no lo hice.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un caso del punto 2.5 del [artículo](https://www.rae.es/dpd/raya) sobre la raya en el DPD:

> 2.5. Las rayas se usan también para enmarcar los comentarios del transcriptor de una cita textual: *«Es imprescindible —señaló el ministro— que se refuercen los sistemas de control sanitario en las fronteras»*.

Como se ve en el ejemplo, las rayas son la única manera de introducir incisos en una cita textual entre comillas («»). Otros métodos para introducir incisos (como las comas o los paréntesis) no tienen este efecto, por lo que un inciso entre paréntesis podría parecer parte de la cita textual. Las rayas son la solución más práctica en este caso.